# Criar uma variável int que reconheça os números em formato de hora

Tags: java, android, data, time, parse

Eu tenho uma variavel int que está pegando o horario atual do android e comparando com mais dua variaveis int do meu banco de dados no parse que contém o horario de abertura e de fechamento de uma empresa, em empresas de horario comercial funciona, mas quando uma empresa abre de dia e fecha de madrugada por exemplo, já tenho problema, pois se uma empresa fecha ás 1:00 e for 00:00, o aplicativo reconhece que está fechado.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm", Locale.getDefault());
Date hora = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

int horaAtual = Integer.parseInt((sdf.format(hora)));

int horarioAberto = Integer.parseInt(parseUser4.get("horaAbertura").toString());

int horarioFechado = Integer.parseInt(parseUser5.get("horaFechamento").toString());


if (horaAtual < horarioAberto) {
    horario.setText("FECHADO");
    horario.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.vermelho));
} else if (horaAtual > horarioFechado) {
    horario.setText("FECHADO");
    horario.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.vermelho));
} else if (horaAtual >= horarioAberto) {
    horario.setText("ABERTO");
    horario.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.verde_limao));
} else if (horaAtual <= horarioFechado) {
    horario.setText("ABERTO");
    horario.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.verde_limao));
}
```

Eu queria saber se tem como por exemplo eu usar algum código que faça reconhecer, 00 < 01 < 02 < 03, e assim por diante, assim como as horas são reconhecidas num relógio normal.

Comment: Que valor tem `parseUser4.get("horaAbertura").toString()` ou `parseUser5.get("horaFechamento").toString()` ?

Comment: O "horaAbertura" contem o horário de abertura da empresa, por exemplo 0700, assim como o "horaFechamento" contém o horario de fechamento, por exemplo 1730.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário considerar de forma separada os casos em que o horário passa de um dia para o outro.

No seu código se horário for das `1730` as `0100` então se considerarmos as horas `1800` ele vai entrar no segundo `if`:

```
else if (horaAtual > horarioFechado) {
```

Porque `1800` é maior que `100` e vai apresentar `FECHADO`.

Para solucionar este problema basta adicionar mais um bloco de if para quando o horario passa de um dia para o outro, assim:

```
if (horarioAberto < horarioFechado){ //horario normal
    if (horaAtual < horarioAberto || horaAtual > horarioFechado){ //if igual ao que tinha
        System.out.println("FECHADO");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("ABERTO");
    }
}
else { //horario que passa o dia
    //teste especifico e diferente para quando passa o dia
    if (horaAtual >= horarioAberto || horaAtual <= horarioFechado){
        System.out.println("ABERTO");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("FECHADO");  
    }
}
```

[Veja os testes desta logica no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ddch5N)

Comment: Putz amigo, nem sei como te agradecer, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado por ter tirado do seu tempo pra me ajudar, abraços!

Comment: @AlekssanderAugusto De nada, boa sorte para o resto do projeto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tudo de bom pra ti!